# Matlab: Numerical array index into a string array (without loops)

Tags: arrays, string, matlab, indexing, numbers

I'm doing a set of problems from the MATLAB's introductory course at MIT OCW. You can see it [here](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-094-introduction-to-matlab-january-iap-2010/assignments/MIT6_094IAP10_assn01.pdf), it's problem number 9, part g.iii.

I have one matrix with the final grades of a course, all of them range from 1 to 5. And I have another array with only letters from `'F'` to `'A'` (in a `'decreasing'` order).

I know how to change elements in a matrix, I suppose I could do something like this for each number:

```
totalGrades(find(totalGrades==1)) = 'F';
totalGrades(find(totalGrades==2)) = 'E';
totalGrades(find(totalGrades==3)) = 'C';
totalGrades(find(totalGrades==4)) = 'B';
totalGrades(find(totalGrades==5)) = 'A';
```

But then, what's the purpose of creating the string array "letters"?

I thought about using a loop, but we're supposed to solve the problem without one at that point of the course.

Is there a way? I'll be glad to know. Here's my code for the whole problem, but I got stuck in that last question.

```
load('classGrades.mat');
disp(namesAndGrades(1:5,1:8));
grades = namesAndGrades(1:15,2:size(namesAndGrades,2));
mean(grades);
meanGrades = nanmean(grades);
meanMatrix = ones(15,1)*meanGrades;
curvedGrades = 3.5*(grades./meanMatrix);

% Verifying 
nanmean(curvedGrades)
mean(curvedGrades)

curvedGrades(curvedGrades>=5) = 5;

totalGrades = nanmean(curvedGrades,2);

letters = 'FDCBA';
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Maybe something like `totalGrades(find(totalGrades==1))=letters(1);` and then `totalGrades(find(totalGrades==2))=letters(2);` and so on...

Comment: or you might want to try something like `arrayfun()`

Comment: This would be a great question to ask your professor. See also: [Matrix Indexing](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html)

Comment: It did change something but I don't know if I require some extra line to convert a number to string. Take a look at my outcome: 

totalGrades(totalGrades==5)=letters(5)

y =

     4
     3
     4
     4
     4
    65
     3
     3
     4
     3
     3
     3
     3
    65
     4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
letters=['F','D','C','B','A'];
tg = [1 2 1 3 3 1];
letters(tg)
```

Result:

```
ans = FDFCCF
```

This works even when tg (total grade) is a matrix:

```
letters=['F','D','C','B','A'];
tg = [1 2 1 ; 3 3 1];
result = letters(tg);
result


result =                                                                                                                                                                             

FDF                                                                                                                                                                             
CCF
```

**Edit (brief explanation):**
It is easy to understand that when you do `letters(2)` you get the second element of letters (`D`).

But you can also select several elements from `letters` by giving it an array: `letters([1 2])` will return the first and second elements (`FD`).

So, `letters(indexesArray)` will result in a new array that has the same length of `indexesArray`. But, this array has to contain numbers from 1 to the length of `letters` (or an error will pop up).

Comment: It would be useful to explain *why* this is the case, since it's the part OP is not understanding.

Comment: Thanks a lot R. Schifini, nailed it. And as always, it was a pretty simple solution. Need to study more.

Comment: You were trying to use logical indexing to change the numbers to letters, but this solution is more a lookup on letters by using total grades as the array of indexes.